# How to do repeated actions in Android?

Tags: java, android

**I use such code:**

```
t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //some action
  }
}, 30000, 30000);
```

If I wrap up application(click Home) and after that recover application then task is canceled. How to solve that problem?

Comment: I try handler.postDelayed and this solve my problem but maybe there is better way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the services for this task: 
[tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)